# pass scope object to service which can watch and update it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written some code which watches a scope variable and updates it which is all working fine. I'm now trying to wrap this up in a service so I need to pass an object to my service and then let the service watch it and update it.

I think the problem is that when passing the object it's being passed by reference but can't be updated, only members can (if I've understood passing by reference correctly.

A simplified version of my code looks like this.

```
angular.module('my.services').factory('myUtils', function ($log, $timeout, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {

    'use strict';

    var myUtils = {};


    myUtils.syncUrlToObject = function(myObject, callback){

        $rootScope.$watch(function(){
            return myObject;
        }, function(newValue, oldValue){


            // Update tmyObject
            myObject = {foo: 'bar'}

            // Run the callback
            callback();

        }, true);

    }


    return myUtils;

});
```

Comment: curious to know..why you are passing scope object to service..and placing watch from there?

Comment: Because it's part of a larger block of code (around 50 lines) which I don't want to have to repeat in all my controllers. All of the code was working when it was in the controller but the only way I can see to wrap it up and keep it DRY is to pass the object which needs to be watched and manipulated to the service.

Comment: then why don't make that object to be as part of the `service` variables

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The object will be different depending on what controller is calling it. Basically the service will sync any object to the url parameters. It needs to watch the object and copy any changes to the URL, similarly it needs to watch the URL parameters and copy any changes back to the object. To do that I need to pass the object which needs syncing to the service function, don't I? I could just put it on the $rootscope but that seems like bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Watchers must be in controller or in directives but not in service . I think .